# Using a CSS border-radius much larger than an elements dimensions

Tags: html, css, dom, css-shapes

Is there any issue with using a `border-radius` that is much larger than an element's dimensions?

For example, if I wanted to make a class `.circle` like so:

```
.circle {
    -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1000px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
}
```

So now I can apply this class to any element to make it a circle, like so:

```
<img width="80" height="80" alt="My Gravatar" class="circle" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b262eb4b3bf006cf68ef60eae63ddffc">
```

I know I haven't run into any issues so far, but am I just setting myself up for more issues down the road?

Comment: People use these tricks for make CSS shapes all the time. No worries so far.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @Diodeus In all those examples, they aren't exceeding the dimensions of the element with the border-radius.  Frshca is asking if exceeding the dimensions is okay.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no issue here at all. You're free to apply the class wherever you'd like, no issues really. Elements smaller than (height or width is less than) `2000px` will become circles, elements larger than (height or width is more than) `2000px` will not become circles, but rather stay their original shapes but have largely rounded corners.

This was brought up in W3 [**here**](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/29?changelog):

> "If any horizontal radius is larger than half the width of the box, it
>   is reduced
>        to that value. If any vertical radius is larger than half the height of the box, 
>       it is reduced to that value. (There are four horizontal and four vertical radii.) 
>       This is an easy algorithm, because it looks at each radius independently of all 
>       others, but it disallows possibly useful borders that combine large and small 
>       radii and it may turn quarter circles into quarter ellipses." - 
>   [The documentation of the `border-radius` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/#the-border-radius)

I should mention that you can use percents as a value, 50% being the max that will create a circle given the element is a square originally. If the element is not a square then it will create an ellipse.

Also note that all values above 50% will be equivalent to 50% when applied to all corners (like the shorthand `border-radius:50%` which applies it to each corner). As jbutler483 [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260547/using-a-css-border-radius-much-larger-than-an-elements-dimensions/18260710?noredirect=1#comment47448677_18260710) in the comments, if it is applied to individual corners, 50% is not the same as 100% because of how they combine with each other. Instead all values above 100% are equivalent to 100%.

It's also important to note that something like [`border:50%`](http://jsfiddle.net/ccbagx1c/) and [`border:really-high-pixel-value`](http://jsfiddle.net/ccbagx1c/1/) can have different effects if the element is not square.

Comment: *note that all values above 50% will be equivalent to 50%* - I don't agree with this.

Comment: @jbutler483 What don't you agree with about it?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/ahbr6Lgb/) != [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/ahbr6Lgb/1/)

Comment: @jbutler483 Ah, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ahbr6Lgb/2/) === [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ahbr6Lgb/3/). I'll clarify

Comment: The difference between the results of border-radius: 50% and border-radius: really-high-pixel-value is an artifact of the [algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#corner-overlap) used for reducing overlapping border curves.

Answer (score 0):

This was [W3 CSS issue-29](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/29), which was [resolved](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008May/0148.html#:%7E:text=define%20what%20happens%20when%20border%20radii%20intersect.) following option 3 in the issue as [documented](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#corner-overlap) in the spec.

If *any* adjacent border radii are so large that they intersect, then *all* border radii are reduced proportionally so that none intersect.

In the particular case that all four radii are the same on a square element, and the radii are larger than half of the box dimensions, they get reduced to half of the width/height so that they end up forming a circle.